# Configure a Gradle Task at Runtime

Tags: gradle

Is It possible to configure inputs of a gradle task at runtime after other tasks have run?

For example I am calculating a `SHA` of a zip in one step, and then uploading the zip with a path consisting of the SHA from a previous step. But when I got get get the value of the `SHA` which is contained in a file via: `def sha = shaFile.text` I get an error: `(No such file or directory)`.

I had always assumed tasks were closures which were run at runtime but I guess that is just the `doFirst` & `doLast`, but the inputs need to be configured already before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is It possible to configure inputs of a gradle task at runtime after other tasks have run?

Think of it this way:

In order for task B to run, task A must run first, that is to say, task B has a dependency on task A.

Refer to [Adding dependencies to a task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks) for more details on task dependencies.

Ok so now we're at the point where we need the *output* of task A (SHA value) as an *input* for task B. Since we have a dependency on task A, Gradle well make sure that task A is executed prior to B's execution.

Here's quick dirty example in [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (should be easily translated to Groovy):

```
tasks {
    val taskA = register("taskA") {
        val shaText = File("sha.txt")
        if (shaText.exists()) {
            shaText.delete()
        }
        File("sha.txt").writeText("abc");
    }
    register("taskB") {
        dependsOn(taskA)
        println(File("sha.txt").readText())
    }
}
```

Ideally, you should create a [custom task type](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html) specifying the [input file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/InputFile.html) and also specifying the [output file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/OutputFile.html) so that Gradle can cache tasks inputs/outputs. Refer to [Incremental tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html)
 for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did in fact just end up writing a custom task though. That seemed to be the easiest thing to do, and kept the `build.gradle` clean.